# Suppressing multiple values in Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rows, multiple-value

Below is an example of code that I have, and I would like it to print a user's account number along with a each procedure number and the sequence number that shows up for that appointment, for example:

```
acc num        proc num  Seq num
--------------------------------
Vxxxxxxxxx26    44.42   1
Vxxxxxxxxx26    57.94   2
Vxxxxxxxxx26    57.32   3
Vxxxxxxxxx26    38.93   4
```

But instead it prints many duplicates of the same thing for the same date and time, for example:

```
acc num        proc num  Seq num
--------------------------------
Vxxxxxxxxx26    44.42   1
Vxxxxxxxxx26    57.94   2
Vxxxxxxxxx26    57.32   3
Vxxxxxxxxx26    38.93   4
Vxxxxxxxxx26    44.42   1
Vxxxxxxxxx26    57.94   2
Vxxxxxxxxx26    57.32   3
Vxxxxxxxxx26    38.93   4
Vxxxxxxxxx26    44.42   1
Vxxxxxxxxx26    57.94   2
Vxxxxxxxxx26    57.32   3
Vxxxxxxxxx26    38.93   4
```

How can I limit it so it only shows 1 set of values rather than 5 set of values?

BTW I am a newbie to Stack Overflow and SQL so please keep that in mind when reviewing. Thank you.

NOTE: It seems as though it is the `OeOrders` table. When this is not JOINED it has the appropriate rows, when it is JOINED it expands with all the multiple rows.

CODE

```
DECLARE
    @StartDate DateTime,
    @EndDate DateTime
    SET @StartDate = '10/28/2013 00:00:000'
    SET @EndDate = '11/28/2013 23:59:000'
    SET @RecordType = '6'

SELECT 
    ,AbstractData.AccountNumber AS AcctNum_2
    ,'I9:'+AbsDrgProcedures.DrgProcedure AS ProcCode_3
    ,AbsDrgProcedures.ProcedureSeqID AS Priority_4

FROM AbstractData
    LEFT JOIN AbsDrgProcedures 
    ON (AbsDrgProcedures.VisitID = AbstractData.VisitID) AND AbsDrgProcedures.VisitID IS NOT NULL
    LEFT JOIN OeOrders 
    ON (OeOrders.VisitID = AbstractData.VisitID) 

WHERE 
    AbstractData.PtStatus <> 'REF'
    AND OeOrders.ServiceDateTime BETWEEN @StartDate and @EndDate
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, didn't catch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select distinct results - `SELECT DISTINCT` rather than `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

Select distinct will filter out duplicates, just add distinct after the select and it should work